# How to reach button from contained in library from .as file

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

What I want to do is to add button as a child to a movie clip which is on stage. Get input in a text field and then save that input into String variable. This button should trigger this actions. Only problem I find is that I can't reach the button which is in library. I have set button AS linkage and I am trying to reach it trough that linkage.

This is the line of code which dosen't work:

```
enterName.addChild(nextButton);
```

Error I get is: **Line 254   1061: Call to a possibly undefined method addChild through a reference with static type Class.**

Comment: What is enterName?  Is it the name of a class?  Or an instance of a class?  Are you using Flex?

Answer (score 0):

Since your button has a linkage, you should **instantiate** it, which means:

```
enterName.addChild(new nextButton());
```

An even cleaner version would be to have your linkage name with a first letter upper case (this is commonly how classes are named). And you could cast this instance as a `DisplayObject` to tell the compiler you know this class extends something you can add to a container:

```
enterName.addChild(new NextButton() as DisplayObject);
```